# The paperclips are on the wrong side

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

The site theme appears to put the content area on a stack of paper with paperclips on it.

However, the paper clips are on the top right:

[image]

Assuming a left-to-right language (the site is in English), unless we are looking at the back of the stack of paper, the paperclips are on the wrong (or, at least, unusual) side.

If somebody handed me a set of papers clipped on the top-right, I believe my reaction would be a silent face-palm and a "why...".

Comment: I... don't think I've ever even noticed those before.

Comment: Well, sure, but I'd probably rather see them gone than moved to the left...

Comment: @enderland I only noticed them because [they give bunny ears to avatars on the profile activity page](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2322/enderland?tab=topactivity).

Comment: @JasonC what has been seen __CANNOT BE UNSEEN__. That's actually pretty funny, I don't know how I never saw that before...

Comment: Oh geez, *thanks*.  Can't be unseen, indeed!

Comment: If they change it, though, they should do it only on main, such that meta *is* the back side of the page.

Comment: those are paperclips!?

Comment: In Arabic and Hebrew they are most certainly in the correct place. [meta-tag:status-declined]

Comment: @Lilienthal But if you remove them, the site will fall apart.

Comment: Im not sure that the standard should apply to digial paperclips though...

Comment: +1 Please fix! Literally unvisitable!

Comment: @Oded Then you have to fix a different problem. In Arabic and Hebrew, other things, such as the submit buttons, the voting buttons and vote count, etc. should be to the right, and the sidebar should be to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the design.

It is indeed meant to invoke the idea of paper clips.

We will fix this when the paper clips stop you from turning the page to the next one.

Comment: "We will fix this when the paper clips stop you from turning the page" - LOL! Is that a planned enhancement?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - just waiting for the HTML specification to catch up!

Comment: That doesn't really answer anything, does it? Of course, the OP knows those are paper clips, he is asking *why* it is by design, when it would be better (in his opinion) to have it on the left. Why exactly can the paper clips not be moved to the left?

Comment: @MaskedMan - why should they?

Comment: For the reasons mentioned in the OP's question. Isn't that what the question was about? Just to be clear on this, I don't care where the clips are, just that this answer doesn't adequately address the OP's question (even though he has "accepted" it).

Comment: @MaskedMan - the answer is "that's how it was designed". You may not find that much of an answer, but that's really all there is to it. The designer who created the designer has left the company, so not something we can get more insight into (at a guess, I'd say it is better on the right because being on the left would disturb the visual hierarchy of the page).

Comment: While that does explain why they are on the right, it doesn't answer why the design cannot be changed. The OP says the clips are on the "wrong" side, which implies asking why it cannot be moved to the correct side. Your "guess" does answer that.

Comment: @MaskedMan the OP tagged this [meta-tag:bug], and this answer says it's not a bug.  "We're not going to fix that" is a valid response to bug reports -- maybe not the one you *want*, but valid.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Alright, I didn't notice the bug tag. I thought the OP was asking for a feature-request. From the description, it seemed that's what his intention was.